# find the equation of the circle that tangent 4 lines

Tags: circles

find the equation of the circle that tangent four lines

(y=x-1)
(y=x+1)
(y=-x+1)
(y=-x+3)

how i can find the center ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJUBX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a simple graph we can easily see that $C(1,1)$ and $R=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$

[image]

thus the equation of the tangent circle is

$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=\frac12$$